# How to find the limit of $x^{\ln(5)/(1+\ln(x))}$?

Tags: limits

Please help me to solve this limit:

$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }x^{\ln(5)/(1+\ln(x))}
$$

Maybe we could do this :

$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }x^\left(\frac{c}{\infty}\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty }x^0 = 1
$$

Am I right ?

Comment: The subscript of your limit should be $x\to\infty$ not $n\to\infty$. And you are wrong; you can't let one part of the expression reach $\infty$ (the denominator of the exponent) while you leave another part of the expression behind (the base of the exponent). Are you aware that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\to e\approx 2.718$ for example? By your logic, that would either be $\lim(1+\frac{1}{n})^\infty=\infty$ or $\lim 1^n=1$, both wrong. What you need to do for this problem is recognize that $x^\alpha=e^{\alpha\cdot \ln x}$.

Comment: Hint: We have $a^b=\exp(b\ln a)$.

Comment: Every time you have $f(x)^{g(x)}$ you do $\exp(g(x) \ln(f(x)))$ now you can pass the limit inside the exponential because it is a continuous function.

Comment: do you mean $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^{\frac{ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}}$?

Comment: yes, thanks for your answers

Comment: $\infty ^0$ is an _indeterminate form_, which is why you can't tell what the expression is just by seeing it is of the form $\infty^0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, forms like $\infty^0$ cannot be evaluated directly. (Neither could $1^\infty$)

For exponential you usually consider taking log.

$$\ln \left(x^{\ln(5)/(1+\ln(x))}\right) = \frac{\ln 5 \ln x}{1+ \ln x} \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln 5 \ln x}{1+\ln x}= \ln 5$$

Therefore the original limit is $e^{\ln 5} = 5$.